# Serialize nhibernate entity to json error: Cannot serialize a Session while connected

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, json.net, nhibernate-3

I'm trying to serialize an nhibernate entity in to json but I always get this error saying Cannot serialize a Session while connected? Does it has something to do with nhibernate proxy?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I started getting the same error when I switched from `System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer` to `Newtonsoft.Json`.

Using the contract resolver from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5926718/913845) fixed this problem:

```
string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(theObject,
                new JsonSerializerSettings()
                {
                    ContractResolver = new NHibernateContractResolver()
                });
```

Answer (score 7):

Yes, this is related to lazy loading. You will need to configure NHibernate to eagerly fetch associations if you want to be able to JSON serialize it. But I would recommend you using view models instead. [Ayende Rahien blogged](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2011/04/10/refactoring-toward-frictionless-amp-odorless-code-the-case-for-the.aspx) about this issue.